# Agile toolkit CRUD

Tags: php, orm, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

I'm testing Agile Toolkit and i don't understand what i'm doing bad.

I've a table named 'families' which CRUD works fine.

Another table named 'subfamilies' with a relationship n to 1 with families and CRUD works fine too.

But here is my problem, in table 'articles' i've a relationship 1 to 1 with families and another 1 to 1 with subfamilies and CRUD works, i can add delete and modify but when add button is clicked, if i select a family on the form, subfamilies combobox shows me all subfamilies not only ones that are from that family.

How can i specify that if a family is selected the combobox from the add form only show subfamilies relatives to that family?

Code:

file ./lib/Model/Articulos.php:

```
class Model_Articulos extends Model_Table {
public $entity_code  = 'articulos';

    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('name')->mandatory(true);
        $this->addField('description')->mandatory(true)->type('text');
        $this->addField('familias_id')->mandatory(true)->refModel('Model_Familias');
        $this->addField('subfamilias_id')->refModel('Model_Subfamilias');

    }
}
```

file ./page/articulos.php:

```
class page_articulos extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $crud=$this->add('CRUD');
        $crud->setModel('Articulos');

        if($crud->grid){
            $crud->grid->getColumn('name');
            $crud->grid->getColumn('familias');    
            $crud->grid->getColumn('subfamilias');    

        }
    }
}
```

And finally you can get the mysql workbench eer model [here](http://casa.cotelo.net/eer-tienda.mwb)

Thank you in advance,

Serxoz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, when you define a model, there is a no sub-link between family and subfamily, so your CRUD wouldn't know about the dependency.

To do what you need, you must fully understand the following two examples:

- http://demo.atk4.com/demo.html?t=20
- http://demo.atk4.com/demo.html?t=22

Next, create a form for adding a new record for Articulous. You will need to use MVCForm but will have to add some additional code for the sub-family field. When you have it done, you'll need to convert your code into a separate class such as Form_Articulos inherited from MVCForm. Your code should go inside the "setModel" method of your form.

Next, extend CRUD like this:

```
class MyCrud extends CRUD {
    public $form_class='Form_Articulos';
}
```

The new form will be used for editing and addition. One remaining thing you may need is to add model-level validation.

```
class Model_Articulous ... {
    ...


    function beforeUpdate(&$data){

        $family_id=$this->getRef('subfamilias_id')->get('familia_id');
        if($family_id != $this->get('familias_id'))
            throw $this->exception('Subfamily does not belong to selected family');
    }
}
```

Comment: Before I convert the form in Form_Articulos class I create a form to add new records in ./page/articulos.php:

$form = $this->add('MVCForm');
$form->setModel('Articulos');

But i don't understand how i can get access to dropdown fields to change it's content.

Comment: and have you looked at example?

Comment: yes, in example setValueList is done before addField, but when i do setModel fields are generated automagically and if i generate fields by myself i don't know how to connect with model.

Comment: LOL, sorry it's not about looking at example, it's about RTFM. 
Sorry again, i'm going to try some things and post again. Thank you!

Comment: Model simply populates the fields on your form. You can get to the fields using $form->getElement('fieldname'), then do anything with it. You can even ->destroy() it.